# Dynamically click the parent checkbox Accordiance using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on parent checkbox  then all the child  in that particular parent checkbox should be checked.but I am running with the  issue like when I click on parent then all the child checkboxes of another parent are getting checked. Please let me know where I went wrong.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left"> 

  <!-- Right side column. Contains the navbar and content of the page -->
  <aside class="right-side"> 
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">

      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Sample</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row cache-automation"> 
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
          <!-- Subject Area -->
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title"> Area</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header --> 
            <div class="box-body subject1">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                         <input type="checkbox" id="chckHead"  class="chckHead" value="subject1"/>
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> Content</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
                                            <label for="checkbox">
                                                List group item heading
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
                                            <label for="checkbox">
                                                List group item heading
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
                                            <label for="checkbox">
                                                List group item heading
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="chcktbl"  />
                                            <label for="checkbox">
                                                List group item heading
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="chckHead"  class="chckHead" value="subject2"/>
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsetwo"> Content</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapsetwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
                                            <label for="checkbox">
                                                List group item heading
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
                                            <label for="checkbox">
                                                List group item heading
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="chcktbl" />
                                            <label for="checkbox">
                                                List group item heading
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="chcktbl"  />
                                            <label for="checkbox">
                                                List group item heading
                                            </label>
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->              
              <!--<div class="box-footer text-right">&nbsp;</div>  -->          
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.col (left) --> 
        <!--/.col (right) --> 

      </div>            
    </section>
    <!-- /.content --> 
  </aside>
  <!-- /.right-side --> 
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
```

and my code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.chckHead').on("change", function() {

        if(!$(this).is(":checked")) {
           $(".chcktbl").each( function() {
              $(this).prop("checked" , false);
           });
        }
        else {
          $(".chcktbl").each( function() {
            $(this).prop("checked" , true);
        });
     }
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you need any further explanation of the code below, just ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your existing code is that is checks all matching checkboxes on the page, not just the related ones. That is because you use the selector `$(".chcktbl")` which selects all elements on the page that have `class="chcktbl"`.

You can simplify that type of code to:

```
$('.chckHead').on("change", function() {
    $(".chcktbl").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

As you also need it to apply to just the closest panel, use `closest('.panel')` and `find()` to localise the matches:

```
$('.chckHead').on("change", function () {
    $(this).closest('.panel').find(".chcktbl").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wak1991z/

### **Update:**

If you want the `checkall` buttons to reflect the individual selections too, you can also do this:

```
// Also make the checkall reflect the all checked state
$('.panel').on('change', '.chcktbl', function () {
    $(this).closest('.panel').find(".chckHead").prop('checked', $(this).closest('.panel').find('.chcktbl:not(:checked)').length == 0);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wak1991z/1/